# Why do retroflex and postalveolar fricatives sound so similar despite the quite different positions of the tongue?

Tags: acoustic-analysis

If they sound so similar, does it mean that they have a larger chance to be free variants of a phoneme and even become the other in a sound change. Do they play different or similar role in sound changes?

Answer (score 2):

Both the retroflex and postalveolar fricatives are sibilants and are therefore [louder than other consonants](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sibilant#Acoustics). /ʃ/ and /ʂ/ are the [two lowest pitched among sibilants](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Postalveolar_consonant#Postalveolar_sibilants).

Urdu inherited Sanskrit /ʂ/ as /ʃ/ (Hindi is also sometimes described as having /ʃ/ rather than /ʂ/). The phonemes /ʂ, ʐ, tʂ, dʐ/ of Serbo-Croatian are realized as /ʃ, ʒ, t͡ʃ, d͡ʒ/ in Croatian and some Bosnian dialects ([Serbo-Croation phonology](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Serbo-Croatian_phonology) on Wikipedia). The postalveolar set of consonants in Slovak is "often pronounced" as retroflex ([Slovak phonology](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Slovak_phonology)), so this might be one case of free variation.

Answer (score 1):

The positions of the tongue are *not* all that different in these sounds. They are only somewhat different, and that similarity in production is why they sound similar. 2 sounds do not have a larger chance of being free variants, or of one becoming the other, in an absolute sense – such a comparison only makes sense given a third "foil". For example [ʃ,ʂ] are more likely to be in free variation than [ʃ,θ] or [ʂ,θ] are (likewise, for one to derive from the other via historical change). Restricting the investigation to the realm of sh-like sounds, you would be looking for perceptual closeness relations among [ʂ ʃ ɕ ç] plus the "whistling" fricative of Shona which does not have a unique IPA letter (close to ʂ, but not the same). A three-way contrast in this set is rare, or non-existent ([ʂ] in Norwegian is best treated as an allophone of /rs/). If you simply mean "are [ʂ,ʃ] perceptually closer than either is to [s θ f χ]", the answer is "yes". Otherwise, there is no way to test the claim.

Answer (score 1):

As someone that comes from Mandarin, retroflex and postalveolar fricatives sound quite different to my ears. The fact is that they are both fricatives and are produced at about the same location in the mouth, so it makes sense that they'd be similar. It sounds to me that the difference is mainly in the way it affects surrounding vowels, and the way it affects the resonance, but I'd have to do some fact checking on that.

Interestingly, in [Taiwanese Mandarin](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Taiwanese_Mandarin#Hokkien-influenced), "the retroflex sounds (zh, ch, sh, r) from Putonghua tend to merge with the alveolar series (z, c, s), becoming more retracted version of alveolar consonants like [t͡s̠ʰ][t͡s̠][s̠][z̠]." This is probably true in various other dialects/accents as well. Note, though, that they are still considered separate phonemes here.

I don't know if they have a "larger chance" to merge. Certainly, a larger chance than two incredibly different sounds, and most sounds in general, but to what extent I couldn't say.